# Preserving A Game Object's Orientation When Snapping It Into An XR Socket Interactor [Unity VR]

Tags: unity-game-engine, orientation, virtual-reality

I'm trying to create a puzzle in VR where the user gets cubes with different colours on each face (side). The goal is to stack the cubes together such that each pair of touching faces has the same colour. I want the cubes to snap together if the faces match and to "repel" each other if not.

I tried using XR Socket interactors to implement the logic. The problem is that as soon as a cube is put into a socket, its orientation changes to the socket default. I want to be able to snap the objects together while preserving their orientation. Any advice would be much appreciated.